# Query and list all the files of a given extension on the phones internal and external storage in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filesystems, dart-pub

Is there a way of printing all the files of a given extension say(.pdf, .mobi, .epub) in both internal and external storage.

I am not interested in a file manager. Just want all files and their paths.

Any package suggestions is appreciated. I tried using the file_manager package. But it lacks this specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can query all files through `rootDirectory.list(recursive: true)`, and check the mimeType of the file. mimeType can be changed to image, video, audio, text.
You need mime_type package for this.

```
List<FileSystemEntity> contentFiles = [];
String mimeType = 'image'

  void queryResult() async {
    final rootDir = Directory('root directory path here');
    Stream<FileSystemEntity> _stream = rootDir.list(recursive: true);
    _stream.listen((event) {
      if (event is File &&
          !isHidden(event.path) &&
          validType(event.path)) {
        contents.add(event);
      }
    });
  }

  bool validType(String path) => mime(path).contains(mimeType);

  bool isHidden(String filePath) => path.basename(filePath).startsWith('.');
```